# Adding a Youtube Video clip

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

This works fine, but it first displays a thumbnail view where i have to click it for the video to play. So i need to remove this thumbnail view, and play the video directly. How can i do this. My code is as follows;

```
- (YouTubeView *)initWithStringAsURL:(NSString *)urlString frame:(CGRect)frame;
    {
  if (self = [super init]) 
  {
    // Create webview with requested frame size
    self = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

    // HTML to embed YouTube video
    NSString *youTubeVideoHTML = @"<html><head> <meta name = \"viewport\" content = \"initial-scale = 1.0, user-scalable = no, width = 480\"/></head><body style=\"background:#F00;margin-top:0px;margin-left:0px\"> <div><object width=\"480\" height=\"256\"> <param name=\"movie\" value=\"http://www.youtube.com/v/oHg5SJYRHA0&f=gdata_videos&c=ytapi-my-clientID&d=nGF83uyVrg8eD4rfEkk22mDOl3qUImVMV6ramM\"></param><param name=\"wmode\" value=\"transparent\"></param> <embed src=\"http://www.youtube.com/v/oHg5SJYRHA0&f=gdata_videos&c=ytapi-my-clientID&d=nGF83uyVrg8eD4rfEkk22mDOl3qUImVMV6ramM\"type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" wmode=\"transparent\" width=\"480\" height=\"256\"></embed> </object></div></body></html>";

    // Populate HTML with the URL and requested frame size
    NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:youTubeVideoHTML, urlString, frame.size.width, frame.size.height];

    // Load the html into the webview
    [self loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];


}
  return self;  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use autoplay parameter. All parameters are described [here](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/player_parameters.html#autoplay).

Comment: something like this <param name="autoplay" value="1"></param> ?

Comment: My God, you even didn't open ref with docs??? have a look there! Yes, you are right.

Comment: I did, i got the param name and values from there.. Just wanted to check if i wrote it properly with the param tag and all.

Comment: You are developer! Check it on the fly! That needs as little as one paste command to modify your code and check it.

Comment: I am not using my MAC at the moment, and that is why i posted it

Comment: Hello again, Adding the param autoplay doesn't work. I still get the thumbnail and i have to click it to play the video